# PHP fpdf issue when my site is on HTTPS

Tags: php, nginx, https, smarty, fpdf

I having a problem with FPDF V1.6

Everything work fine when I reach my website on HTTP but when I reach it by HTTPS the pdf will never finish to load I will receive only a part of it.

I'm on a Nginx server running php 5.4

Cloudflare is doing the HTTPS. 
Does any one have a hint where to look?

Comment: Generation of PDF should not be affected by HTTP / HTTPS protocol...

Comment: I know, that is why i'm posting here I don't know what can cause that.
Also I try to disable cloudflare and same result...

Comment: I have xampp install on my pc with apache. I try on HTTPS and it work fine    . So could it be related to Nginx

Comment: Check the error logs. Let PHP also create an error log, as (I assume) you're on a production environment.

Comment: Nginx is not generating any error for this issue

Comment: I’m having the same issue here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40163580/fpdf-script-timed-out
Did you find any solution ?

Comment: Sorry. I didn't found anything. I decide to migrate to apache.

Comment: Same problem here, it seems that fpdf does not generate behind cloudflare, did you find any solution?