# FPDF Script Timed Out

Tags: php, pdf, nginx, fpdf, cfpdf

I’m working with the FPDF library to generate PDFs.

At some point I include an image into the pdf (in the header) and do:

```
require_once APPPATH . '../vendor/setasign/fpdf/fpdf.php';

class cifpdf extends FPDF {

public function __construct($params = array())
{
    $this->CI = &get_instance();

    $orientation = array_key_exists('orientation', $params) ? $params['orientation'] : 'P';
    $mesure = array_key_exists('mesure', $params) ? $params['mesure'] : 'mm';
    $format = array_key_exists('format', $params) ? $params['format'] : 'A5';

    parent::__construct($orientation, $mesure, $format);
}

public function Header()
{
    $logo = base_url('assets/promoters-landingpage/img/logo-inverted.png');
    // Logo
    $this->Image($logo, 10, 6, 30);

    $this->Rect(10, 17, 129, 0.1);
    // Saut de ligne
    $this->Ln(10);
}
```

My issue is coming from the `$this->Image($logo, 10, 6, 30);` line

Looking at the Image function in the pdf vendor library, I tried to debug and found out the bug was coming from this part:

```
function Image($file, $x=null, $y=null, $w=0, $h=0, $type='', $link='')
{
    // Some Code
    if(!isset($this->images[$file]))
    {
        // Some Code

        $type = strtolower($type);
        if($type=='jpeg')
            $type = 'jpg';
        $mtd = '_parse'.$type;
        if(!method_exists($this,$mtd))
            $this->Error('Unsupported image type: '.$type);
        $info = $this->$mtd($file);
        // Some Code
    }

    // Some Code
}
```

So the exact line that causes the time out error is `$info = $this->$mtd($file);` (line 885 in the library).

I;m not sure what $mtd is? It seems defined a few lines above in `$mtd = '_parse'.$type;` but they do not associate it to $this. Not sure what is this.

I’m using Nginx. That same piece of code was working fine on Apache 2.

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Check PHP version on both hosting - Nginx and Apache2

Comment: Thank you JackTheKnife for your prompt response. My php version is 5.4.9 on Apache2 and 5.6.26 on the net Nginx Server. Do you think that’s what caused the issue?

Comment: Yes. I had similar issue on an old PHP and I have ended up with an old fpdf library which was working.

Comment: If it is possible to have multiple PHP instances on a hosting where you have Ngnix then try to do that and force to use PHP 5.4 on that site to narrow it down to PHP version rather than web server.

Comment: Thank you so much, you’re saying you ended up with an old pdf library .. on which php version ?

Comment: I dont know how to do multiple instances of php, I’ll rather just downgrade

Comment: PHP 5.4 but most recent version of the lib at that time (beginning of 2015) was not working either so I got I think 2nd version back which was working.